# webdav for wsgi/python?

Tags: python, webdav, wsgi

I want to add WebDAV to [whiff](http://whiff.sourceforge.net). This would be easy if I could find a simple WSGI component that implements WebDAV. I found http://pyfilesync.berlios.de/pyfileserver.html, but it seems to insist on using an external configuration file. I want to control everything via a Python API. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently picked up PyFileServer for further development:
    http://code.google.com/p/wsgidav/

After the config file is read, it's only a plain dictionary, that is passed to the WSGI Application object's constructor.
So it should be pretty easy to do what you want.

I didn't use whiff yet, but you are invited to contact me or join the project :-)

Comment: I've recently begun looking at WsgiDAV as a starting point for a CardDAV server implementation. It's very well developed, but can you think of any reasons why it would not be suitable for CardDAV?

Comment: No reasons that I am aware of :) Of course some extensions are needed, like the REPORT command, but that seems doable.
I suggest to move the discussion to
    http://groups.google.com/group/wsgidav
martin